# React Router Redirect - add parameter to pathname

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, react-router, react-router-dom

I use React Router Redirect and I have a parameter `newId` which is some number and I want to add it to url. For example if "newId" is 10, I want to go to "/admin/add-questions/10".

It's something like below, but `:${newId}` doesn't work. It redirects me to "admin/add-questions/:$%7BnewId%7D". I also tried `:newId` and other solutions and I can't find how to do it :(

```
render() {

    const newId = 10;

     return (
        <Redirect
          to={{ 
            pathname: '/admin/add-questions/:${newId}',
            state: { key: 'value' } }}
        />
      );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider replacing your *single quotes* with *backticks* to let *template literals* work properly.

```
pathname: `/admin/add-questions/${newId}`,
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you :) And it should be also without ":", only ${newId}